# How to segregate a stored procedure into a table row by row?

Tags: asp.net, sql

There is a stored procedure which contains many insert, update, delete and truncate statements. I want to group all the statements one by one into a table.

For example:

```
create proc Get_Tables as
begin

UPDATE BB_FMCTransactionsTwo SET wsTradeDate = wsSettleDate WHERE wsEntryCode = 'NRT'
UPDATE BB_FMCTransactionsTwo SET wsOK = 1, wsSpecialLogic = SpecialLogic FROM BB_EntryCode INNER JOIN BB_FmcTransactionsTwo ON EntryCode = wsEntryCode
UPDATE BB_FMCTransactionsTwo SET wsFMCFtNt = '' FROM BB_EntryCode INNER JOIN BB_FmcTransactionsTwo ON EntryCode = wsEntryCode   WHERE wsBS <> 'B' AND ( FMCFtNtB IS NULL OR  FMCFtNtB = 'PR' )
UPDATE BB_B204_Tran SET AMOUNT = dbo.BCA_AMT(Desc1, Desc2, Desc3, Udesc1, Udesc2, Udesc3) WHERE TRANIND = 14 AND  PORTTYPE IN (2,3)
DELETE BB_B204_Tran WHERE TRANIND = 14 AND PORTTYPE IN(2,3) AND (Quantity IS NULL  OR ISNUMERIC(Quantity) = 0 OR Quantity = -1 OR ISNUMERIC(AMOUNT) = 0

end
```

**Required:**

I want to insert the update statements, delete statements into a table one by one...

Create a stored procedure which divides the stored procedure based on type of statements (`Insert`, `Update`, `Truncate`) and inserts that into a table row by row. So that the table looks like below.

Table:

```
Sl.No Statement
1 UPDATE BB_FMCTransactionsTwo SET wsTradeDate = wsSettleDate WHERE wsEntryCode = 'NRT'
2 DELETE BB_B204_Tran WHERE TRANIND = 14 AND PORTTYPE IN(2,3)
```

Comment: Please try SQL Trigger, you can record all

Comment: Can u post the code for the above example?

Comment: Ya i'm sure..There is no need of ordering...just i want the insert,update,delete statements separately in a table Marc..

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented for your first update statement and assume that your AuditTable will have one column SQLData and so you need to store these SQL Statements in your store procedure and if you have used any variable then you need to store into SQL Data variable and insert into Audit Table. it may help you.

```
declare @@SQL1 varchar(max)


UPDATE BB_FMCTransactionsTwo SET wsTradeDate = wsSettleDate WHERE wsEntryCode = 'NRT'
set @@SQL1 = 'UPDATE BB_FMCTransactionsTwo SET wsTradeDate = wsSettleDate WHERE wsEntryCode = ''NRT'''
insert into AuditTable (SQLData) values(@@SQL1)
```

For Variable:

```
DECLARE @@wsEntryCode VARCHAR(100)
SET @@wsEntryCode='NRT'
PRINT 'UPDATE BB_FMCTransactionsTwo SET wsTradeDate = wsSettleDate WHERE wsEntryCode = ''' + @@wsEntryCode + ''''

insert into AuditTable (SQLData) values(@@SQL1)
```

Comment: There will be 1000's of such update statements...I cant declare everytime right..I want an SP which will loop till the last statement and insert all the statements into a table

Comment: if you are using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Version then it has Audit facility, you need to implement it. Please refer : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Please refer it:http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1649/auditing-select-statements-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: I want to store all the update statements into one table..what has Auditing to do with this?

Comment: As per my knowledge, you need to write all Statement in SQL Variables or use need to use any software to get this information and tool may not give you based on procedure so u may need to search based on tables.